# Select Dropdown option based on its text not value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select an item of dropdown by its text. I can't select them by value because value will be different everytime.

```
   $("#rn_SelectionInput_7_attend_session_time option").each( function(){
      alert($(this).text()==radioValue);// this evaluate to true when a matching item is found

     if( $(this).text()==radioValue) 
     {
        $("#rn_SelectionInput_7_attend_session_time").selectedIndex=$(this.index()); // this doesn't do anything
     }
   });
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the selected property of the option element to make it as selected

```
$("#rn_SelectionInput_7_attend_session_time option").filter(function () {
    alert($(this).text() == radioValue); // this evaluate to true when a matching item is found
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == radioValue
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2c52m/)

- [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) - to find the option element with the given text
- [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) - set the selected property to true

Comment: Thank you for the code. But it only works if I change prop to attr. Any ideas? is this browser specific?

Comment: @BishnuPaudel it is depending on jQuery version used...  which is the jQuery version used

Comment: it's good if it's not browser specific. the page i am working now uses 1.4.2 and I can't change . Thanks,

Comment: @BishnuPaudel if you are using jQuery 1.4.2 then you need to use `.attr()`, if jQuery >= 1.6.4 then `.prop()`